# How to get an error message in R when trying to enter a duplicated key in a MySQL table?

Tags: sql, r, rmysql

Take a SQL table defined by:

```
CREATE TABLE `raw_dummy_code` (
  `code` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `datestart` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateend` date DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and a R data frame defined by:

```
raw_dummy_code <- data.frame(code = c(4, 4L, 4L),
                             datestart = c("2001-01-01", "2002-01-01", "2002-01-01"),
                             dateend = c("2001-12-31", "2500-01-01", "2500-01-01"),
                             description = c("old","recent","recent"),
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

When I try to insert the data frame in the database :

```
con <- RMySQL::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "test")
RMySQL::dbWriteTable(con, "raw_dummy_code", raw_dummy_code, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
RMySQL::dbDisconnect(con)
```

`RMySQL::dbWriteTable` inserts only one row in the database. This is normal, since there are duplicated rows, but the problem is that there is no error message returned. 
How to get the error message from MySQL when trying to enter a duplicated key?